# canvas.create_text is showing text under an image instead of on top

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Here is my code - I am trying to create_text and lay it over the image but when running the code i can only see it even appears if i create it in position 0,0, the other text at position 400,263 does not shows (because it layered under the image)

```
window = Tk()
window.title("Flash Card")
window.config(pady=50, padx=50, background=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=526)
french_background = PhotoImage (file ="images/card_front.png")
canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=french_background)
canvas.create_text(0, 0, text="French", fill= "black" , font=("Ariel", 40, "italic"))
canvas.create_text(400,263, text=random_french, fill="black", font=("Ariel",60,"bold"))
canvas.config(bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

[output of the code on my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sexA.png)

Comment: When I run your code the text *is* on top of the image.

Comment: Any idea why it is showing under on my computer? I been spending hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: No. I wouldn't have expected it to be underneath the image because the graphic objects on a `Canvas` are drawn in the order they're created (i.e. they appear back-to-front with the back-most ones being drawn first).

Comment: When I run this code the text is appearing over the image, as I would expect since it is created after the image. Please create a complete [mcve], then copy and paste it to a new file on your machine to make sure it actually illustrates the problem you're having.

Comment: I added an image of the output to the original post.

Comment: Images are always rectangular arrays of pixels, so to make one appear to have rounded corners is simulated by making portions of each corner transparent. That is why you can see the text which is under the image.

Answer (score 0):

> canvas.create_text is showing text under an image instead of on top.

> I am trying to create_text and lay it over the image but when running
> the code i can only see it even appears if i create it in position
> 0,0, the other text at position 400,263 does not shows (because it
> layered under the image)

The problem can be fixed by reducing font sizes to 40 and 30. And set the canvas.create_text coordinates to `canvas.create_text(120, 30,...)` instead of `canvas.create_text(0, 0, ...)`

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Flash Card")
window.config(pady=50, padx=50, background='green')

canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=526)
french_background = PhotoImage (file ="p2.png")
canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=french_background)
canvas.create_text(120, 30, text="French", fill= "black" , font=("Ariel", 40, "italic"))
canvas.create_text(400,263, text='random_french', fill="yellow", font=("Ariel",30,"bold"))
canvas.config(bg='red', highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use `canvas.create_text` after `canvas.grid`

```py
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

canvas.create_text(0, 0, text="French", fill= "black" , font=("Ariel", 40, "italic"))

canvas.create_text(400,263, text=random_french, fill="black", font=("Ariel",60,"bold"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).